# InvalidCredentials: Unable to retrieve the FCM server key for the recipient's app

Tags: expo

InvalidCredentials: Unable to retrieve the FCM server key for the recipient's app. Make sure you have provided a server key as directed by the Expo FCM documentation.

In expo push notification tool i am getting this problem after doing everything

Comment: @tahamaatof yes u have to change the projectId accoding to your build project id if you do not find out the projectId let me know i will tell u project id of expo build and written in app.json file is same and in this is same
 token = (
    await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
      projectId: "",
    })
  ).data;
  console.log(token);